# How do I print variables in Rust and have it show everything about that variable, like Ruby's .inspect?

Tags: debugging, rust, println

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert("Daniel", "798-1364");
    println!("{}", hash);
}
```

will fail to compile:

```
error[E0277]: `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     println!("{}", hash);
  |                    ^^^^ `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
```

Is there a way to say something like:

```
println!("{}", hash.inspect());
```

and have it print out:

```
1) "Daniel" => "798-1364"
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) formatter:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert("Daniel", "798-1364");
    println!("{:?}", hash);
}
```

This should print:

```
{"Daniel": "798-1364"}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between println's format styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100077/155423)

Comment: For custom strict a, you'll need to decorate them with the #derive(Debug) trait. http://rustbyexample.com/trait/derive.html

Answer (score 35):

Rust 1.32 introduced the [`dbg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html) macro:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert("Daniel", "798-1364");
    dbg!(hash);
}
```

This will print:

```
[src/main.rs:6] hash = {
    "Daniel": "798-1364"
}
```