# What is the difference between println's format styles?

Tags: rust

I'm so sorry to ask such a simple question... A day ago, I started learning Rust and tried the `println!` method.

```
fn main() {
  println!("Hello {}!", "world");
}
-> Hello world!
```

And then, I found other format styles: `{}, {:}, {:?}, {?}`, ...

I know that `{}` is instead `String`, but I don't understand the other format style. How do those styles differ from each other? I think `{:?}` is array or vector. Is it correct?

Please explain these format style with sample code :(

Comment: See here https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html and here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rust/362/hello-world/1248/advanced-usage-of-println

Comment: @aSpex Thx!! It is that I want!!! :)

Answer (score 24):

For thoroughness, the `std::fmt` formatting syntax is composed of two parts:

```
{<position-or-name>:<format>}
```

where:

- `<position-or-name>` can be the argument position: `println!("Hello {0}!"`, "world");`, note that it is checked at compile-time
- `<position-or-name>` can also be a name: `println!("Hello {arg}!", arg = "world");`
- `<format>` is [one of the following formats](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits), where each format requires the argument to implement a specific trait, checked at compile-time

The default, in the absence of position, name or format, is to pick the argument matching the index of `{}` and to use the `Display` trait. There are however various traits! From the link above:

- nothing ⇒ Display
- `?` ⇒ Debug
- `o` ⇒ Octal
- `x` ⇒ LowerHex
- `X` ⇒ UpperHex
- `p` ⇒ Pointer
- `b` ⇒ Binary
- `e` ⇒ LowerExp
- `E` ⇒ UpperExp

and if necessary new traits could be added in the future.

Answer (score 7):

`println!()` is a macro that uses the [`std::fmt` syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html) and `{}` indicate parameters. If the brackets are left empty (`{}`), the corresponding argument needs to implement the `Display` trait and if they contain `:?` it means that the argument's `Debug` implementation should be used instead.

The bottom line is that it is not the parameters' type that is relevant here, but [the traits they implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits). For instance, `Vec`tors implement `Debug`, but they don't implement `Display` and that is why you can't use `{}` against them while `{:?}` works just fine.