# `Option<std::string::String>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter

Tags: rust

I have the csvdump.rs code as:

```
impl EvaluatedTxOut {
    #[inline]
    fn as_csv(&self, txid: &str, index: usize) -> String {
        let address = match self.script.address.clone() {
            Some(address) => address,
            None => {
                debug!(target: "csvdump", "Unable to evaluate address for utxo in txid: {} ({})",
                txid, self.script.pattern);
                String::new()
            }
        };

        // (@txid, indexOut, value, @scriptPubKey, address)
        //format!("{};{};{};{};{}\n",
        format!(
            "{};\n",
            //&txid,
            //&index,
            //&self.out.value,
            //&utils::arr_to_hex(&self.out.script_pubkey),
            &self.script.address
        )
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Compiling rusty-blockparser v0.8.2 (C:\Users\allsc\Downloads\Compressed\rusty-blockparser-master\rusty-blockparser-master)

error[E0277]: `Option<std::string::String>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
--> src\callbacks\csvdump.rs:203:13
    |
203 |             &self.script.address)
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Option<std::string::String>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
    |
    = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Option<std::string::String>`
    = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::__export::format_args` which comes from the expansion of the macro `format` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `rusty-blockparser` (bin "rusty-blockparser") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `rusty-blockparser` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

Can some one please help with this ?

Comment: Perhaps `self.script.address` should just be `address`.

Comment: Does [this question on Rusts formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100077/what-is-the-difference-between-printlns-format-styles) help?

Comment: This code does not compile due to the undeclared type and macro, it's better to create a [mre]. The exact answer, however, depends not only on this, but also on some explanation of the goals - what are you trying to output, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To display variables, Rust uses traits. Currently, you're using `format!("{}", ...)`, note the `{}`. The fact that the brackets are empty means you use the trait named `Display`. To resolve your issue, either you `impl Display for Option<String>`, or you use another trait. For debugging prints, you usually want to use `format!("{:?}", ...)`, saying to use the `Debug` trait. Option implements `Debug` if and only if the type it depends on does also implement `Debug`, which is the case of `String`. `Option` doesn't implement `Display` however because this trait is meant to display to the user (and `Option` doesn't have one way to display that everyone wants).

You can find everything you need about formatting on https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html