# How to print the contents of a syn::Expr with println?

Tags: rust

I am trying to output the contents of a `syn::Expr` to the console, but get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_string` found for type `&syn::Expr` in the current scope
   --> derive/src/lib.rs:165:40
    |
165 |                 println!("Expression: {:#?}", expr.to_string());
    |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: the method `to_string` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `syn::Expr : std::string::ToString`
            `&syn::Expr : std::string::ToString`
            `syn::Expr : std::string::ToString`
```

It is not clear to me what "trait bounds" are or how to satisfy them. Are there any easy ways to output the contents of this variable?

Comment: *It is not clear to me what "trait bounds" are* — a quick [search on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=rust+%22trait+bounds%22) quickly identifies a chapter in *The Rust Programming Language*. You can then read the [current version of that chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`syn::Expr`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.9/syn/enum.Expr.html) is documented as [implementing the `Debug` trait](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.9/syn/enum.Expr.html#impl-Debug), so you use the `Debug` formatter:

```
extern crate syn; // 0.15.4

fn example(expr: syn::Expr) {
    println!("{:#?}", expr);
}
```

**However**, all `Debug` implementations in `syn` are guarded by the Cargo feature `extra-traits`. So in order to use those `Debug` impls, you have to specifically enable that feature in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
syn = { version = "0.15", features = ["extra-traits"] }
```

You can read more about `syn`'s optional Cargo features [in their README](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn#optional-features).

---

See also:

- [How do I print variables in Rust and have it show everything about that variable, like Ruby's .inspect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39039700/155423)
- [What is the difference between println's format styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100077/155423)
- [Should I implement Display or ToString to render a type as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27769681/155423)
- [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)

Comment: Thanks for responding to my dumb question. Unfortunately, I had tried that formatting earlier and got a different error: `^^^^^ 'syn::Expr' cannot be formatted using '{:?}' because it doesn't implement 'std::fmt::Debug'`. It seems like I might be working with a non-standard `syn::Expr`? (note I did use `{:#?}`, but error is missing the hashtag)

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi it's impossible to debug code that we cannot see. Please review what a [MCVE] is and how to produce and provide one. I can say that [the code provided compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=05630cb519d72d16f99dd58166a0d74a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster, unfortunately I am too unfamiliar with the code base and Rust to reasonably come up with a mcve. That is my bad, and reflects itself in the quality of my post. I appreciate your responses

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Take another look at this answer. I added a part about the `extra-traits` feature. I hope this helps.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Why this doesn't appear in the doc directly ? ["When built, the documentation will then announce whether it was built with the foo feature enabled or disabled, which might be handy"](https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-cfg_attr.html)

Comment: @Stargateur it's actually documented [at the top-level of the crate](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.9/syn/#optional-features). You could file an issue with the library to add that info to each instance of the trait, but that would probably force the maintainers to no longer be able to use `#[derive(...)]`, which would be very annoying.